# How to retrieve ng-repeat jSON value in IONIC controller

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

this is snippet of my controller

```
$rootScope.maxPage= function() {
    tanyaService.getApiMaxPage($rootScope.getPilihSubTest).success(function(dataAmbilPage){
      $rootScope.varMaxPage = dataAmbilPage;

    });
  };
    $rootScope.maxPage();
```

JSON

```
[{"maxPage":7}]
```

and succeded to shown at view with this below

```
<div ng-repeat="page in varMaxPage" align="center">
 {{page.maxPage}}
</div>
```

How to get Value maxPage (7) of JSON on my controller above?

Thank You

Comment: use $rootScope as dependecy injection in controller .  Everything is fine here  Did you check in console ?

Comment: yes fine and there is no problem on view, but the problem is i don't know how to get value {page.maxPage} on controller.

Comment: This is the correct way . I am asking that have u checked console for any error? check console.log(dataAmbilPage); for value is showing or not ,What you are getting in view?

Comment: thank you solved with console.log($rootScope.varMaxPage[0].maxPage);

Comment: That's great . You was not parsing response perfectly , Flag post helpful if valuable for you, :)